# Can I avoid wasting barrels?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze

After a few failed attempts on Lord Fredrik, I went back to Funky's to purchase a hoard of Dixie barrels for extra health. Unfortunately, whenever I enter the level without a companion (usually because I died to lava), Dixie immediately pops out of one of my reserve barrels even though there's a perfectly good regular barrel just a few steps ahead.

Is there a way to prevent the game from automatically using the barrels I brought in my inventory?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a companion with you as you immediately enter a level, the companion barrel you bought won't activate until you've lost your current companion. As a result, you can do this:

1. Enter a level with a companion barrel near the beginning.
2. Get your companion.
3. Immediately exit the level.
4. Buy a companion barrel and use it on the level or boss giving you a hard time.
5. Profit.

Comment: This doesn't solve the main issue. If I die without using up all my barrels (again, by falling into lava), I reenter the level without a companion, wasting a spare barrel. Your solution works when goingback to Funky's to refill barrels and it's what I did when I needed to do that, but it doesn't solve the wastage when restarting the level.